# What grammar construction is this?

Tags: word-order

I came across the sentence

> Environmental considerations and Australia’s absorptive capacity are
>   conspicuously absent, **as is the investment infrastructure required
>   to** provide services to the growing population.

Could it have been

> Environmental considerations and Australia’s absorptive capacity are
>   conspicuously absent, **as the investment infrastructure is required to**
>   provide services to the growing population?

Why is this grammar construction used here?

Comment: "required to provide services to...." is a reduced clause modifying **infrastructure**.  You can understand it as "(which is) required...", and **as is** repeats the  "are absent" predicate, only in the singular, "as is (absent) the ..."

Comment: Clear error. There's no modification here at all. It's a coordination construction. The expression commencing with "as" is not a clause but a preposition phrase. We understand that both the _Environmental considerations and Australia’s absorptive capacity_ **and** _the investment infrastructure required to provide services to the growing population_ are conspicuously absent. A simple coordination of two like facts.

Comment: This Complex Sentence has a main clause and a dependent clause. The main clause is: Environmental considerations and Australia’s absorptive capacity are conspicuously absent || the dependent: as is the investment infrastructure required to provide services to the growing population. The dependent clause adds information about one more thing absent, the infrastructure, and as a sentence: The investment infrastructure required to provide services to the growing population is (absent). "as" is the subordinating conjunction introducing the clause. I'll add a link about Dependent Clauses.

Comment: http://examples.yourdictionary.com/complex-sentence-examples.html

Comment: Bill is spot-on. The meaning is thus "Environmental considerations and Australia’s absorptive capacity **and** the investment infrastructure required to provide services to the growing population are conspicuously absent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, the straightforward form of the sentence would be

> Environmental considerations and Australia’s absorptive capacity are conspicuously absent, as the investment infrastructure required to provide services to the growing population is.

But when you have a very long subject (*the investment infrastructure required to provide services to the growing population*) and a short verb phrase (*is*) in a subordinate clause, it can be difficult for the hearer or reader to parse, and English allows you to swap them: this process is called [extraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition), and gives you the original sentence

> Environmental considerations and Australia’s absorptive capacity are conspicuously absent, as is the investment infrastructure required to provide services to the growing population.

When the subject itself has an embedded relative clause, it is also possible to extrapose only that clause. So if the subject were the fuller *the investment infrastructure that is required to provide services to the growing population*, you could extrapose that relative clause:

> Environmental considerations and Australia’s absorptive capacity are conspicuously absent, as the investment infrastructure is that is required to provide services to the growing population.

In principle, you can do this even with the "reduced relative clause" *required to provide services to the growing population*, but as others have pointed out, the result (your second sentence) has another, more obvious, reading with a different structure. But in speech, and with a comma after "is", I can imagine somebody saying your second sentence.

I agree with others that this "as is" has become a set phrase, but I think in this case it is completely analysable and doesn't have a special meaning.

Comment: But it sounds awful. "Environmental considerations and Australia’s absorptive capacity are conspicuously absent, as the investment infrastructure is that is required to provide services to the growing population." I'll stick with YOUR straightforward interpretation, which coincidentally, happens to be mine. I had to revise my comments because of "as." I couldn't make up my mind what it was, though most of the time I see it as a subordinating conjunction. How to fit (absent) after the verb, meant using it as "understood." I appreciate the support. I owe you one.

Comment: You're massively over-analysing and have thus missed the obvious fact that the two elements are in coordination. "As is" effectively means "and". The meaning is thus "Environmental considerations and Australia’s absorptive capacity **and** the investment infrastructure required to provide services to the growing population are conspicuously absent. And there is no 'reduced' relative clause present: the subordinate clause commencing "required" is a non-finite past-participle clause postmodifying 'investment infrastructure'.

Comment: @PaulM: that is indeed the meaning, but it's a strange analysis, since it splits the coordinated subject, with the VP in between. And there is indeed a reduced relative clause, specifically a "[reduced object passive relative clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_relative_clause#Non-finite_types)".

Answer (score 1):

This sentence puts together three parallel ideas:

> 1. Environmental considerations *are conspicuously absent*
> 2. Australia’s absorptive capacity *is conspicuously absent*
> 3. The investment infrastructure required to provide services to the growing population *is conspicuously absent*

The first two ideas are put in parallel with a simple **and**. The third idea is put in parallel using the conjunction [as](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as) with the meaning **in the same way**. here is another example of this usage:

> **As** is often the case with children, Amy was completely better by the time the doctor arrived

They could all have been paralleled using **and**, but the author chose for reasons of literary style to use a different method with the last item.

In your alternative sentence, **as** now takes on the meaning **because**, which suggests a causality that does not exist in the original sentence.

Answer (score -1):

> Could it have been as the investment infrastructure is required to [...]?

No. "As is" is a fixed phrase. The "as-is" part of the sentence means:

> The investment infrastructure required to provide services to the growing population is also conspicuously absent

In this case, "as is" means something like "as well as"; it introduces another item which has the same property (being conspicuously absent).

Moving is as you suggested ends up with this sentence:

> "Environmental considerations and Australia’s absorptive capacity are conspicuously absent, **as the investment infrastructure is required to** provide services to the growing population".

This version means something different. This version means that Environmental considerations and Australia's absorptive capacity are absent **because** investment infrastructure is required.

Comment: Downvoter: What is wrong with the answer?